# How to center-align 2 objects in Tinkercad without moving one of them?

Tags: alignment, tinkercad

How can I align one object to the center of another - without moving that second one?

When I select 2 objects in any order and then align them via the center button, it moves BOTH objects.

I want however to move only one of them. Locking the reference object does not help though.

Answer (score 2):

So I found this out finally:

You select 2 objects, click on the "align" button and then on the object that you want to align TO. Then align and the object you selected will not move.